# Extract Feefo JSON array into Javascript, display as HTML list

Tags: javascript, json

I'm learning Javascript and JSON at the moment but really confused by it all.

I'm trying to extract data from a JSON array, I've got to this point

```
$(function(){
    var $reviews = $('#reviews');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "https://api.feefo.com/api/10/reviews/all?merchant_identifier=pub-insurance-4u-co-uk&fields=reviews.service.rating.rating,reviews.service.review,reviews.customer.display_name",
        success: function(reviews) {

        $.each(reviews, function(i, review) {
        $reviews.append('<li>name: '+ review.display_name +', review: '+ review.review + ', rating: '+ review.rating + '</li>');
    });
   }
 });
});
```

I can't seem to get much further at the moment. I've read about JSON.parse(), perhaps that is what I need. Any help / advice GREATLY appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var $reviews = $('#reviews');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "https://api.feefo.com/api/10/reviews/all?merchant_identifier=pub-insurance-4u-co-uk&fields=reviews.service.rating.rating,reviews.service.review,reviews.customer.display_name",
        success: function(reviews) {
        //console.log(reviews);
        $.each(reviews.reviews, function(i, review) {
        $reviews.append('<li>name: '+ review.customer.display_name +', review: '+ review.service.review + ', rating: '+ review.service.rating.rating + '</li>');
    });
   }
 });
});
```

It is helpful to log the object and take a look at it in the console. Then you can see the structure and print what you like.

That's what I did :)
Here is a screenshot:

[image: console output]

And here is the fiddle:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yup8gms/)

Comment: Excellent!!! So simple.... thanks very much for your help!! Finally I can move forward with this!